# svmono + newtx + \footnotesize = excessive horizontal spacing in math

Tags: math-mode, spacing, footnotes, newtxmath, sv-classes

Feeding the input

```
\documentclass{svmono}%%% v5.6 from http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}%% The math font should be loaded after the text font according to the NewTX manual.
\begin{document}
\noindent\(f(x)\)

\noindent{\footnotesize\(f(x)\)\par}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` results in

[image: output].

As you see, in `\footnotesize` (e.g., in footnotes), the horizontal white space between  and the left opening parenthesis ( is excessive: it is even larger in `\footnotesize` than in normal size.  This doesn't look nice: the overall font shrinks, but some distances unluckily grow instead of shrinking!

- Who is the culprit?
- What to do to get the spacing in math mode in footnotes right if we insist on using NewTX fonts with SVMono (which is, actually, suggested by the §2.3 of the SVMono reference guide)?

Answer (score 1):

svnono isn't involved here, you would see the same in `article`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\showoutput
\noindent\(f(x)\)

\noindent{\footnotesize\(f(x)\)\par}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
....\mathon
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.66
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/10 ¹
....\kern0.4
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/10 x
....\kern0.18498
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/10 º
....\kern0.29999
....\mathoff
```

and

```
....\mathon
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/8 f
....\kern3.344
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/8 ¹
....\kern0.4
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/8 x
....\kern0.40399
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/8 º
....\kern0.4
....\mathoff
```

This looks like a bad kern value *in the font* so it is not fixable from within TeX other than manually applying a negative space to correct. You should report this to the font maintainer.

---

What you can do is avoid the 8pt font with the dubious kern and use scaled 10pt instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\DeclareFontShape{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}{
   <-6.3> \ntxmath@scaled ntxmi5
%   <6.3-8.6> \ntxmath@scaled ntxmi7 % from 6.3 up to, but not including, 8.6
   <6.3-> \ntxmath@scaled ntxmi%
}{}

\showoutput
\noindent\(f(x)\)

\noindent{\footnotesize\(f(x)\)\par}
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
....\mathon
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/8 f
....\kern1.328
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/8 ¹
....\kern0.4
....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/8 x
....\kern0.148
....\LMS/ntxsy/m/n/8 º
....\kern0.4
....\mathoff
```

Comment: The kern might be off with newtx (is it \kern3.344 that is wrong?). However, I do see that `svmono` is involved, at least, to some extent. To see this, consider the result of using the `article` class (without \showoutput): https://i.imgur.com/HtU4lG7.png .  Now, compare where the left opening parentheses end with `svmono` and `article`.  With `svmono`, the footnotesize ( ends more to the right than the normalsize (, which is weird.  With `article`, the footnotesize ( ends more to the left than the normalsize (, which is somewhat more normal.

Comment: @GeekestGeek I think footnotesize is slightly different size so things move around a bit when you change class but the font with the dubious  kern is used in the range 6.3pt-8.6pt so the issue is basically the same whatever class you use

Comment: @GeekestGeek my longest period for replying to a longtable bug report is 25 years. It's all spare time volunteer activity, and not everyone has spare time all the time, give it a few days at least.

Comment: The maintainer has just submitted a new version to CTAN. I am happy. Thanks! I cannot test a new version myself easily and quickly at the same time (since I work with a stock version supplied by Ubuntu), but if you can test, or if the new version makes into TeXLive (that I can probably install locally) soon, I'd be glad to know.